# Разница между многопоточностью, асинхронностью и многопроцессорностью в Python (CPython)?

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность

Наиболее популярная и "стандартная" реализация CPython имеет такую вещь как `GIL` — Global Interpreter Lock.

Представим ситуацию: имеется две задачи `task1`(поиск n-ой цифры Pi) и `task2`(n-ое число Фибоначчи). Тогда в случае `асинхронного` выполнения (имея в наличии gil) выполнение по времени будет длиться столько же / больше, чем при синхронном выполнении?

И допустим второе: если запустить эти две задачи в разных потоках, то при наличии gil(который препятствует одновременному выполнению разных потоков), можно ли говорить о том, что многопоточность хуже, нежели многопроцессорность (ведь новый экземпляр процесса будет выполняться параллельно/на другом ядре)?

Comment: используемые вами слова не имеют закреплённых определений) ваши вопросы не понятны. Если в python использовать в лоб потоки, то ваша программа будет выполняться дольше чем в одном. По ассинхронности: если вы обращаетесь к принтеру синхронно / асинхронно - принтер будет думать одинаково. Многопоточность при обращении к одному участку памяти хуже многопроцессорности - непонятно. Лучше вернитесь к "земным" конкретным вопросам)

Comment: @EugeneDennis скажите, что необходимо уточнить, просто мне очень важно понять разницу. Я имею в виду, что если стоит блокировка, то по времени что одно, что второе тоже самое. Но не уверен, что это так

Comment: @EugeneDennis ну и если исходя из данных примеров. без принтеров и пр.

Comment: [вот хорошая статья на английском с пояснениями...](http://masnun.rocks/2016/10/06/async-python-the-different-forms-of-concurrency/)

Comment: @MaxU я видел, но будь у меня суперский английский я бы не написал на стак

Comment: @kot_mapku3, [на русском...](https://compscicenter.ru/media/slides/python_2015_autumn/2015_12_07_python_2015_autumn_3KfewPJ.pdf)

Comment: @kot_mapku3 treading - мучаете GIL потоками, subprocess/multiprocessing - юз ядер. Будете делать задачки первым получится дольше, вторым быстрее

Comment: @EugeneDennis а зачем вообще тогда сделали модуль thread, если в итоге есть async/await и multiprocessing?

Comment: @kot_mapku3 языку почти 30 лет... ништяки не сразу были)

Comment: @EugeneDennis а, ну вообще тоже верно :)